# Edges (relationships) available only for specific users

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a model which allows users to navigate between positions (nodes) using various techniques (edges). Basically to traverse the positions graph using their own specific edges, which are unique and available just for them.

I want every user to be able to create their own edges(techniques) between  nodes (positions). I've considered having technique edges to all have the same name/type - something like "LEADS_TO", but their properties will be different (name, description and most importantly, reference to user who is allowed to use the edge - basically a creator of that edge).

[image]

This means that during graph traversal, I'll have to filter only edges which have the the `createdBy` property matching with the `userId`. 
Also, this model expects that if there will be 1000 users using the app, there will likely be 1000 unique edges (techniques) between 2 nodes (positions).

Would this be correct approach or is my graph thinking/understanding conceptually wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do what you want :

- an edge with a property `user_id` that is a string. So like you said you will have multiple edges between your nodes `pos1` & `pos2` (on for each user)
- an edge with a property `user_id` that is an array of string. So you will have  one edge between your nodes `pos1` & `pos2`, but the size of the array will match the number of user
- prefix each edge's type with the `user_id` : `USER_2_LEADS_TO`

The choice depends on the type of your queries and also on  hte volumetry, ie the average number of relationship you will have between your nodes `pos1` & `pos2`.

As a first approach, your choice is good.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! 

I'm currently experimenting with techniques also being nodes and having 2 types of edges - STARTS and ENDS. So basically the graph looks like `(Position1)<-[:STARTS]-(Technique)-[:ENDS]->(Position2)` now. Because Technique is a node, owner of the technique can connect to it with an edge (saying he's the owner).

Will see if this model works fine, if not, I'll switch to the one I've proposed in the question and you've approved. Thanks!